# HTML: Select size different without options

Tags: html, css

this might be a simple select box problem, but I don't find an answer so far:
In my view, there are several multiline select boxes in a row, which are all defined to size=9. I use the size attribute instead of height because it fits the lines (no lines are cutted). Now my problem is that they got different height when they have no options in the select defined.

The options are filled with AJAX, but at the beginning some of them are empty.

You can view my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/nq3gtb7u/5/ (It's okay in IE, but doesn't work in FF or Chrome)

However, I found out that the problem is the font-family Helvetica, Arial, while it works perfectly with nothing defined or Courier for example.

```
select.wrong
{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
.wrong option
{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

select.right
{
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
.right option
{
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

<select class="wrong" size="9" style="width:40%;">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
<select class="wrong" size="9" style="width:40%;" >
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select class="right" size="9" style="width:40%;">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
<select class="right" size="9" style="width:40%;" >
</select>
```

Now I wonder what I can do to make them the same height with or without options. I tried to set the height of the options, which have a small effect. If I set it like this

```
.wrong option
{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    height: 9.75pt;
}
```

it is okay for FF at least, but not for Chrome. Besides, it looks dirty to me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is Courier a build in font or do you need to import it?  from a very quick google I think it needs importing,  try added a 2nd font that work on the end and see if that works

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Courier isn't the problem, it was just an example for a font that would work. Times New Roman would do it, too, but not Helvetica, Arial, which is the font that we use. Also, I wonder if replacing the size attribute to a defined height is the only solution to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select` elements have different heights because `option` elements have line height and padding. The empty `select` elements have no option lines, so there is nothing to apply padding or line height to. Your browser is guessing the right height, but it fails obviously.

I would just set a min-height for empty `select` elements.

Comment: sorry I edited the wrong post - "I am guessing you will populate it later."  needs to go

Answer (score 0):

I have found a hack that works but I don't know why you want an empty select,

I am guessing you will populate it later.

just put am empty option in the select

```
<select class="wrong" size="9" style="width:40%;" >
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Update:

this is all the code I used in your fiddle example.

HTML:

```
<select class="wrong" size="9" style="width:40%;">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>D</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
    <select class="wrong" size="9" style="width:40%;" >
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select class="right" size="9" style="width:40%;">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>D</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
    <select class="right" size="9" style="width:40%;" >
    </select>
```

CSS:

```
select.wrong
{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
.wrong option
{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

select.right
{
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
.right option
{
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. When I add an empty option to the select in my jsfiddle example, the "empty" select gets even smaller... Just when I add some text in it it get the same height. Guess I take the min-height instead. This might cause that the lines are cut when the list gets longer than this, but I can accept this bahavior...